# How to manage Camel K routes via API(or other alternative ways)?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-k

I have a Camel K application which contains multiple routes(each route is a Java file). my goal is to manage the routes status, for instance start certain routes and stop other running routes.

Currently I start and close the routes manually using `kamel run XXX.java --pod-template pod_template.yaml --property=file:logging.properties ...`, I am wondering what is the best way to achieve managing routes status via API?

My goal is achieving below using API:

- start a route
- stop a route
- list available routes

I have asked the question under [apache/camel-k](https://github.com/apache/camel-k/issues/2824) but still confused about the Integration CRD mentioned in the answer.

I have found that Camel K has API [Camel K API](https://camel.apache.org/camel-k/1.7.x/apis/camel.html#camel.apache.org/v1) unfortunately I haven't figure out how to call the APIs if it is possible?

Can someone share knowledge and help me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You an use the `kamel` CLI to start and list the `Integration`s available, ie:

```
$ kamel run Sample.java
Integration "sample" created
$ kamel get
NAME    PHASE   KIT
sample  Running default/kit-c82emh1c11s7ki7ijq0g
```

The above will use Kubernetes Custom Resource to create an `Integration` and list the `Integration` accordingly

There is no direct way to pause/stop/resume a route. The best thing I can suggest is to have a route per Integration and stop it via `kamel delete` CLI or equivalent Kubernetes API